# Cant Install NMAP due to unmet dependecies!

Tags: dependencies, nmap

I cant install nmap due to following unmet dependencies

```
HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install nmap
[sudo] password for rohan: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
nmap : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.9) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3 is to be   installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I already tried following commands but no luck :

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Tried Searching Dependency itself....

```
~$ apt-cache search libstdc | grep libstdc++6
libstdc++6 - GNU Standard C++ Library v3
libstdc++6-4.7-dbg - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-4.7-dev - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (development files)
libstdc++6-4.7-doc - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (documentation files)
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-arm64-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3
libstdc++6-armhf-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3
libstdc++6-powerpc-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3
libstdc++6-ppc64el-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3
libstdc++6-4.4-dbg - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-4.4-dev - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (development files)
libstdc++6-4.4-doc - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (documentation files)
libstdc++6-4.4-pic - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (shared library subset kit)
libstdc++6-4.6-dbg - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-4.6-dev - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (development files)
libstdc++6-4.6-doc - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (documentation files)
libstdc++6-4.6-pic - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (shared library subset kit)
libstdc++6-4.7-dbg-armel-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-4.7-dbg-armhf-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-4.7-dev-armel-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (development files)
libstdc++6-4.7-dev-armhf-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (development files)
libstdc++6-4.7-pic - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (shared library subset kit)
libstdc++6-4.7-pic-armel-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (shared library subset kit)
libstdc++6-4.7-pic-armhf-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (shared library subset kit)
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-arm64-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-armhf-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-powerpc-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-ppc64el-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-armel-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3
libstdc++6-4.9-dbg - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-4.9-dbg-arm64-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-4.9-dbg-armel-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-4.9-dbg-armhf-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-4.9-dbg-powerpc-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-4.9-dbg-ppc64el-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
```

And installing it....

```
~$ sudo apt-get install libstdc++6 -yReading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libstdc++6
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1629 not upgraded.
```

Tried installing Aptitude but.....

```
~$ sudo apt-get install aptitude
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 aptitude : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.9) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

HELP!!!

Comment: YES...i have 4 of them

Comment: Please run these commands one after the other: `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, and `sudo apt-get -f install`. Then try again...

Comment: didnt worked bro

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the dependency. In the apt-get install log you will see that there's a missing dependency :

> libstdc++6

So in order to fix this try to search for it to make sure you have it available:

```
apt-cache search libstdc | grep libstdc++6
```

or

```
apt-cache show libstdc++6
```

From my output I see:

```
:~$ apt-cache search libstdc | grep libstdc++6
libstdc++6 - GNU Standard C++ Library v3
libstdc++6-5-dbg - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-arm64-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3
libstdc++6-armhf-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3
libstdc++6-powerpc-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3
libstdc++6-ppc64el-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3
libstdc++6-4.7-dbg - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-4.7-dbg-armel-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-4.7-dbg-armhf-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-4.7-dev - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (development files)
libstdc++6-4.7-dev-armel-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (development files)
libstdc++6-4.7-dev-armhf-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (development files)
libstdc++6-4.7-doc - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (documentation files)
libstdc++6-4.7-pic - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (shared library subset kit)
libstdc++6-4.7-pic-armel-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (shared library subset kit)
libstdc++6-4.7-pic-armhf-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (shared library subset kit)
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-arm64-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-armhf-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-powerpc-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-ppc64el-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-4.9-dbg - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-4.9-dbg-arm64-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-4.9-dbg-armel-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-4.9-dbg-armhf-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-4.9-dbg-powerpc-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-4.9-dbg-ppc64el-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-4.9-dbg-s390x-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-5-dbg-alpha-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-5-dbg-arm64-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-5-dbg-armel-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-5-dbg-armhf-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-5-dbg-hppa-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-5-dbg-m68k-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-5-dbg-mips-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-5-dbg-mips64-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-5-dbg-mips64el-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-5-dbg-mipsel-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-5-dbg-powerpc-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-5-dbg-powerpcspe-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-5-dbg-ppc64-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-5-dbg-ppc64el-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-5-dbg-s390x-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-5-dbg-sh4-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-5-dbg-sparc64-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-alpha-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3
libstdc++6-armel-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3
libstdc++6-hppa-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3
libstdc++6-m68k-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3
libstdc++6-mips-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3
libstdc++6-mips64-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3
libstdc++6-mips64el-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3
libstdc++6-mipsel-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3
libstdc++6-powerpcspe-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3
libstdc++6-ppc64-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3
libstdc++6-s390x-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3
libstdc++6-sh4-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3
libstdc++6-sparc64-cross - GNU Standard C++ Library v3
```

So... The first one will do for me.

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6 nmap -y
```

Notice that I've included nmap as well so that you will get nmap after libstdc++6.

## Method 2 & 3

Is to try a "different" package manager and that is aptitude.

#### Aptitude

Will try to install or fix all your missing dependencies you will just have to select if you want or don't want to follow it's guidelines. Unfortunately I haven't used it too much, but each time I had to use it it always solved w/e issues I had with apt.

To install it :

```
 sudo apt-get install aptitude -y
```

Then to run it :

```
 sudo aptitude install nmap
```

Comment: Tried installing dependency itself....it says "The following extra packages will be installed:
  libstdc++6
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1629 not upgraded."........................also installing aptitude shows same umnet dependency...so cant install aptitude

Comment: Edit the post with the log from aptitude and libstdc++6

Comment: There you go bro!

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get upgrade -y `